# How do I register an IBindingTypeConverter in ReactiveUI

Tags: reactiveui

I'm attempting to use the "new" binding code for ReactiveUI and when I do wire my view model property to my control I get the following error:

Additional information: Can't two-way convert between `<type1>` and `<type2>`. To fix this, register a IBindingTypeConverter

So... how do I register an IBindingTypeConverter ? I'm struggling to find an comprehensible example.

---

*n.b. the code that's throwing the error is **not relevant** to this question, it may in itself be wrong but that is an entirely different issue*

Comment: It turns out that my problem was a bug, so I have now made an accepted contribution to open source...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way to do it is via [Splat's](https://github.com/paulcbetts/splat) service locator:

```
Locator.CurrentMutable.RegisterConstant(
    new MyCoolTypeConverter(), typeof(IBindingTypeConverter));
```

**Update:** If you're using RxUI 5.x, it's "RxApp.CurrentMutable"

Comment: But splat isn't referenced...?